# ToolBar in Navigation Based Application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

Since my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609520/what-kind-of-project-type-for-tableviewsuite-app) I'm moving ahead. My Navigation Based Application has to contain toolbar at the bottom of UIViewController. I googled a couple of hours and found a lot of regarding stuff.... well at least I've found this page:

http://frog.io/blog/ios-toolbars

Implemented and got my toolbar buckled up. There's only problem that no single bar button item is visible. So, I need two advices:

1. How to make em visible?
2. Is this approach correct enough? I mean wouldn't it be rejected by Apple?

Comment: Ok. I don't where I went wrong at the first time, but now this example works fine. The second question is still actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a UIToolbar to a UINavigationController based application is actually deceptively easy. Per the [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is a built-in UIToolbar, which is hidden by default.

To show the toolbar try this in your UIViewController subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

To add items to the toolbar, you simply use the `- (void)setToolbarItems:(NSArray *)toolbarItems animated:(BOOL)animated` during `- (void)viewDidLoad` or similar.

You will need to remember to hide the toolbar during `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` unless you want it to hang around as other UIViewControllers are pushed and popped.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what about the method I used? Will Apple like it?